# Do hazel-colored eyes change colors (depending on surroundings) or is that an optical-illusion? Why is the hazel pigment so sensitive to light?

Tags: coloration-discoloration, light-sensitivity, pigment, iris, pupil

**Do hazel-colored eyes change colors (depending on surroundings) or is that an optical-illusion?**

**Why is the hazel (and blue) pigment so sensitive to light?**